# make org "c-c c-c" actually do something useful on a simple line of text

Tags: org-mode

how can one teach emacs to do something useful here?

for example if the current line contains the word "FOO" anywhere, change it to whatever the string returned by special-lisp-function-001

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can attach something to `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c-final-hook`:

> Hook for functions attaching themselves to ‘C-c C-c’.
>
> This can be used to add additional functionality to the C-c C-c key
>   which executes context-dependent commands.  This hook is run after any
>   other test, while ‘org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c-hook’ is run before the first
>   test.

To add something to a hook, we use `add-hook`:

```
(add-hook 'org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c-final-hook
          (lambda () (message "yeah, you got \"%s\"" (word-at-point))
            t))
```

Now, when you press <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>, and org has no other action for the place that point is at, it'll send a message in the minibuffer. Obviously you can change this as necessary.

Note that we explicitly return a non-nil value so that `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c` knows to stop running other functions in `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c-final-hook` once we hit this one.